# How to find wikidata entries with a property

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to learn sparql by thinking of problems to solve, with a  view to one day writing a wikidata bot, whilst I use SQL every day, I find sparql confusing.

What I thought I would do is try to list everyone of a first name, that does not have the P735 "given name" attribute, I have got it to list 10 humans called Neil but cannot find how to only show those without the attribute (or to not show duplicates)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel
WHERE { 
  ?item rdfs:label ?itemLabel.
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .  
  FILTER(STRSTARTS(?itemLabel, "Neil "@en)).
} limit 10
```

Comment: absence of information is done via `FILTER NOT EXISTS`. For example, `FILTER NOT EXISTS {?item wdt:P735 ?gn}` in your case.

Comment: Duplicates occur because of labels in multiple languages. You can add `FILTER (lang(?itemLabel) = "en")`

Comment: note, your filter `strstarts` is expensive as it needs a full scan, there is not fulltext index by default A performance optimized Wikidata specific query: `SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel
WHERE { 
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
   bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org";
   wikibase:api "EntitySearch";
   mwapi:search "Neil";  
   mwapi:language "en".
   ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item.
 }?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .  
FILTER NOT EXISTS {?item wdt:P735 ?gn}
SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".}
} limit 10`

Comment: without the filter you can see 38 entities with `Neil` in their label. Only one of them has no given name property.